# D3.js svg.diagonal issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, diagonal

I have this little issue : I'm not able to draw a curved line with json data.

Here's go my code

```
    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();
groupe.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",diagonal
        .source({x:250, y:500})
        .target({x:400, y:300}))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width","2");
```

Here I put some data, but when i try with

```
.source({'x':function(d) {return d.x},'y':function(d) {return d.x})
```

I habve an error in the console and I'm not able to draw the lines

Do you know where is my error ?

My data looks like this

```
var data = [
    {"x":250,"y":500,"width": 100, "height": 100, "nx":400, "ny":300, "class":"brief", "name": "Prise de Brief"},
    {"x":400,"y":300,"width": 150, "height": 150, "nx":600, "ny":450, "class":"conception", "name": "Conception"},
    {"x":600,"y":450,"width": 150, "height": 150, "nx":900, "ny":500, "xI":600,"yI":450,"wI": 50, "hI": 50, "xlink": "img/hexagone_plein.svg", "class":"crea", "name": "Création graphique", "id": "crea"},
    {"x":900,"y":500,"width": 150, "height": 150, "nx":1150, "ny":350, "class":"dev", "name": "Développements techniques"},
    {"x":1150,"y":350,"width": 100, "height": 100, "nx":1300, "ny":500, "class":"recette", "name": "Recette"},
    {"x":1300,"y":500,"width": 100, "height": 100, "nx":1500, "ny":650, "class":"mel", "name": "Mise en ligne"},
    {"x":1500,"y":650,"width": 100, "height": 100, "nx":1500, "ny":650, "class":"garantie", "name": "Garantie"}
];
```

Comment: Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="Mfunction (d) {return d.x},400Cfunction (d) {return d.x},350 400,350 400,300"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the syntax wrong for source functions, as well as the data already being an array, maybe this will work?

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();

groupe.selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",diagonal
      .source(function(d){ return {"x":d.x, "y":d.y};})
      .target({x:400, y:300}))
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .attr("stroke-width","2");
```

Comment: Thank you a lot but it doesn't work, and the error change

Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M,C,NaN ,NaN ,"

Comment: I think `.data([data])` should be `.data(data)` as it is already an array. Have you tried that?